# Ban/Suspension applies to all sites?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, ban

Do bans and suspensions apply to your account on all SE sites or only the one from which the discipline originated?

The private message I received does not provide an answer to this.

It is also not discussed here: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Comment: To provide some background. I was attempting to show some of my professors the differences in community reception between well worded, clean, succinct questions and poorly worded and vague examples. Needless to say my examples didn't last very long ;)

Comment: Are you suspended or did you get a question ban?  None of your sites are at 1 rep currently, so it doesn't look like you are suspended anywhere.

Comment: No it was just a warning. I was considering some of my thesis work on the sociology of online communities like SE, and wanted to make sure that I won't get too severely banned if I do what I mentioned above in small amounts.

Comment: Hmm, well, that's a tricky situation.  I'm wondering if using the existing corpus wouldn't provide a more objective sample and keep you out of hot water.  You could always ask permission to do so, but I have no idea how it would be received.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suspension is usually on a per site basis.

After all why should you be punished on Cooking for something you did on Android (to pick two sites at random)?

However, this does not mean you can indulge in the behaviour that got you suspended on other sites.

Comment: They are very rare, but I have seen suspensions that are exchange-wide (not likely to be true in this case, however, if the user is posting on Meta).

Comment: @jonsca: When researching a rule-violation-temp-ban user today I found only one instance of someone having been banned across several sites. But I was specifically only searching for rule-violation bans though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I won't dig out the one instance I'm certain of as not to call out the user and protect their privacy, but the mod who requested it must have known the punishment existed through another example of it.

Comment: @jonsca: I wasn't looking to oust any such accounts, just confirming that in my experience (very limited) it appears to be *very* rare indeed. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, maybe I needed an additional "very" in my statement ;)

Comment: @jonsca: a wider search didn't reveal any more examples than that very one.. Maybe 3 'very's? :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters I couldn't tell you for sure.  For various reasons, I don't think they advertise such things.

Comment: It *is* quite rare that a network-wide suspension is necessary or would be productive, but we do have the ability to suspend people network-wide. I can't speak to whether or not folks who request it are aware that it's possible. People do request things we simply can't do once in a while, so it could either be that they've seen a precedent or they just assumed it'd be a logical thing to be able to do (which in this case is also true :)).

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the suspension is valid for the site for which the user is notified. That is because the moderators of a site don't moderate all the Stack Exchange sites.

What can happen is that the behavior of a user is noted from the moderators of different sites, who report what they noticed to the Stack Exchange staff. At that point, Stack Exchange site could suspend the user in all the sites where s/he has an account.
I guess that, if that happens, the user would receive more than one notification of suspension, or a notification followed by an email written by one of the Community Coordinators.